# Using Bootstrap with React: Bootstrap dropdown menu does not open

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-4

**DISCLAIMER:** This question has been previously asked but not in a react context and the answers provide are not completely applicable to my case.

I am getting started with using Bootstrap with React by following this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-react-a354715d1121/).

After installing Bootstrap, jquery, and popper:

> npm install bootstrap jquery and popper.js

And adding them to **src/index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ThemeSwitcher from './components/themeSwitcher'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';

ReactDOM.render(  
    <ThemeSwitcher />
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

And creating the **Themeswitcher** component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ThemeSwitcher extends Component {

  state = { theme: null }

  resetTheme = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ theme: null });
  }

  chooseTheme = (theme, evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ theme });
  }

  render() {

    const { theme } = this.state;
    const themeClass = theme ? theme.toLowerCase() : 'secondary';

    return (
      <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center position-absolute w-100 h-100 align-items-center align-content-center">

        <span className={`h1 mb-4 w-100 text-center text-${themeClass}`}>{ theme || 'Default' }</span>

        <div className="btn-group">

          <button type="button" className={`btn btn-${themeClass} btn-lg`}>{ theme || 'Choose' } Theme</button>

          <button type="button" className={`btn btn-${themeClass} btn-lg dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split`} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span className="sr-only">Toggle Theme Dropdown</span>
          </button>

          <div className="dropdown-menu">

            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={e => this.chooseTheme('Primary', e)}>Primary Theme</a>
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={e => this.chooseTheme('Danger', e)}>Danger Theme</a>
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={e => this.chooseTheme('Success', e)}>Success Theme</a>

            <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>

            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={this.resetTheme}>Default Theme</a>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    );

  }

}

export default ThemeSwitcher;
```

This is what I get as a result:

[image]

So I believe that **bootstrap** works fine. But when I click nothing happens so I guess the problem lies somewhere with the integration of jquery?
**PS:** This is what I get in the inspection:
[image]

Comment: This is because the dropdowns rely on the bootstrap js file **which you have not got loaded in**. And to be honest, when it comes to bootstrap js powered elements and react, I would recommend you just create the functionality manually rather than loading in boostrapjs/popper/jquery for a simple dropdown

Comment: Why would you recommend that?

Comment: Because it saves you loading in entire additional libraries for the sake of a single element

Comment: @GBWDev but if I'm using a lot of bootstrap elements in my projects, then it would make sense.

Comment: Not necessarily. Just depends on whether a 'lot' of those elements depend on Bootstrap js and jquery

Answer (score 1):

Following from the guide you linked, it looks like you've missed a dependency - `Bootstrap.js`

The required imports in the required order for **index.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min'; // you forgot this
```

It's probably better to just use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) though.

Comment: Yes that's true! THanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Bootstrap v4 you can use `<button/>` element instead of `<a/>`, so you don't have to pass event.

Then, are you sure that capitalized values classes exists in bootstrap?
I think there is not `btn-Primary`, but there is `btn-primary`

Moreover, I suggest you to use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) though.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the is File which is required for any interactivity ( like button drop-down)

Using bootstrap directly in react is not advisable. You are 
 likely to run into problems like this. I'd advise you to use reactstrap or react-bootstrap ( I prefer the later) if you want to use bootstrap in your react app.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding this as answer when what you state has already been pointed out and explained?